# Mutli Parameter Linq Query

Tags: c#, linq

The following code gives digits whose name is shorter than their value. I can't understand how LINQ understands that index should be the array index of element. Can somebody explain me...

```
 string[] digits = { "zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", 
                     "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine" };

 var shortDigits = digits.Where((digit, index) => digit.Length < index);
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question but it seems you are describing a coincidence, it might seem less understanding if you change the strings in the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I can't understand how linq understands that index should be the array index of element.

It's calling [the overload which takes a predicate which is *given* the value and the index](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549418.aspx), always. That's the whole purpose of that overload.

From the docs for the `predicate` parameter:

> A function to test each source element for a condition; the second parameter of the function represents the index of the source element.

Answer (score 0):

There's no magic behind it. This specific overload of `Where` does something like this internally:

```
var index = 0;
foreach (var item in collection)
{
    if (predicate(item, index++)) {
        yield return item;
    }
}
```

where `predicate` is the lambda that you are passing in and `collection` is the array of digits.